# Data discrepancy between Google Analytics 4 and Universal Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

Google Analytics 4 is showing incorrect data for April month report. For example, Google Analytics 4's  Page path and screen class Report shows below data for April month:
[Page path and Screen Class Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTKWA.png)

While Universal Analytics' s All Pages report shows below data:
[All Pages Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFPHs.png)

There is a significant difference in page views. I understand GA4 measures differently than Universal Analytics so it will never be a perfect match. But this is a pretty big difference. I am experiencing same issue with all the reports.